# Will MySQL transaction initiated from a PHP db abstraction library lock a table?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I'm wondering if a MySQL transaction initiated from PHP will lock a table so that I can generate my own random values that can be written to a column that has a unique constraint without fear of collision?

Let's say I want to write a new row to a table where there is a unique constraint on the `uuid` column.  So I might do something like this:

```
$mysqlDB->beginTransaction();
$isUnique = false;
$randomstring = randomstring();
while(!$isUnique) {
    $cnt = query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE uuid = $randomstring");
    if($cnt < 1)
        $isUnique = true;
    $randomstring = randomstring();
}
query("INSERT INTO TABLE fields..., uuid = $randomstring";
$mysqlDB->completeTransaction();
```

Can a MySQL transaction started from a mainstream PHP database abstraction library accomplish this without any chance of collision?

YEs, and assuming it is InnoDB

Comment: Assuming innodb? Still trying to grok the real question here. Have you looked at using a unique index?

Comment: correct, using InnoDB, i updated question with that info

Comment: This is a bad idea to even try. The table could potentially be locked for a long time if your random string is bad.  What you should do is add a unique constraint for the uuid and just insert the record until it succeeds. If your randomstring doesnt you will have one attempt on average.

Comment: @ficuscr @hanyolo oh, i updated my qeustion to say specifically that the column `uuid` has a unique constraint on it.   Would a db transaction help in anyway?

Comment: I'm on the same page as @HanYolo. Don't bother with the lock, avoid the side effects, just leverage the unique index and handle the exception / regen UUID and re-insert. You can certainly lock from a PHP client as described though if ever desirable.

Comment: Ok what you guys say makes sense.  And just so I'm clear, i guess this means db transactions actually do lock tables then?

Comment: Yeah, I'm no export on that though... https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html Think this might be the scenario where you get those gaps in auto increments after a rollback. Can pretty much guarantee this will be most efficient approach though, more atomic than what you can do with a transaction - or at least feels like it. Under the hood could be more similar than I realize.

Comment: "However, only an index record lock is required for statements that lock rows using a unique index to search for a unique row."... always a confusing topic because so many variables... take `isolation level` for example.